SSMS - Automatically save SQL query result to a file
I use SSMS for SQL queries. I've find how to make JSON result with FOR JSON AUTO or FOR JSON PATH.
Now I want to schedule request result to a JSON file with MaintenancePlan.
How I can do that with SSMS, without bcp ?

Why without BCP?

Because I would like to use the result to notify by email in case of error.
With BCP, the result is distorted and it's difficult to put my queries on line (they are long).

"With BCP, the result is distorted and it's difficult to put my queries on line (they are long).' - I don't understand what you mean by this. Sounds like you're using BCP incorrectly possibly, as you should be able to create a JSON file with proper formatting.
